# Is sentence "It don't seem right" correct?

Tags: grammar

In the song "In the Army Now," there is this sentence:

> Your finger is on the trigger but **it don't** seem right

Shouldn't "don't" be replaced with "doesn't"?

Comment: Yes it should be _doesn't._  Substituting _don't_ for _doesn't_ is very common in informal casual speech and song lyrics - much like substituting _ain't_ for _isn't._  (At last in the U.S.) For a non-native speaker, it is probably best to avoid both of these usages completely.

Comment: *Don't* will be considered incorrect on any language test you take that asks for answers based on standard Englis. However, as @Adam mentioned, you will run across popular usages including *don't* and *ain't* in everyday speech, movies, songs, etc. I agree that non-native speakers should avoid these nonstandard uses, because it will make you sound unnatural. But it is good to be able to recognize common nonstandard uses, and *don't* and *ain't* are among the commonest.